# Basic steps to add Siri functionality to radio app

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I would like to be able to tell Siri "Hey Siri, play [app name]" for my radio app, and have it play a default station. What are the basic steps to achieve this? I'm not really looking for a Siri Shortcut per se, but built in "play" functionality. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the following with Swift.

However, without any coding, Hey Siri, open [App Name] is possible automatically.

To add custom functionalities such as play a default station, please refer to [this link](https://medium.com/better-programming/add-siri-support-to-your-ios-app-in-minutes-using-swift-86970322286)